# Highly available Cloud SQL Postgres: Any downtime when adding a read replica?

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, replication, google-cloud-sql

I have highly available CloudSQL Postgres instances.
If I add read replicas to each one will it cause any downtime, will it require a restart?
It is highly likely there is no restart at all, I could not find something clear on the GCP Cloud SQL documentation.

Comment: There is no downtime to add a read replica. I am not sure what you mean by **to each ones**.

Comment: If you want an official answer from Google, do not request one on Stack Overflow. Open a support ticket with Google Cloud Support or post the question to Google Insiders (an invitation only forum).

Comment: Google employees **might** contribute to a question/answer but do not expect their participation. Use the official Google Cloud Support channels. Please read this guide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- According to [Cloud SQL MySQL doc](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/replication/create-replica#create-2nd-gen), if binary logging is not enabled then it requires a restart.
- Creating Cloud SQL replicas in [Postgres](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/replication/create-replica#create-2nd-gen) and [SQL server](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/replication/create-replica#create-2nd-gen) don't have this caveat

Answer (score 0):

Read replicas do NOT require any restart or downtime

Comment: Just add any reference to the official gcp docs to complement your answer.

Comment: I am waiting for official answer accompanied with documentation on official docs. On non HA they used to cause downtime and some lag.

Comment: But you are having HA setup as you mentioned in question. Read replica will be created from standby database instance. Hence, no possibility of downtime and restart. Also, read replicas need not to be synchronous

Comment: Yes, I actually know that likely there won't be a restart, and the replication implementation is asynchronous. My problem is that they don't reference it officially on the documentation (wherever I searched), so I assume some of the people from GCP here on stack overflow will answer.